# The plugin `path_provider_android` doesn't have a main class defined

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dependencies

Since i wasn't using the plugin path_provider anymore i tried to delet it, then it gave me a warning, so i deleted a folder caled "data" know i'm trying to do `flutter pub get` and it shows this error
[image]

I tried deleting the pubspec.lock and doing `flutter clean` but nothing, when i try to run the app shows this

[image]

this is my dependecies

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `Invalidate caches/restart`
but not sure it will works or not

[image]

Comment: sorry, where should i try that?

Comment: i'm in visual studio code, how can i do that?

Comment: is there any option in vs code?

Answer (score 0):

**April, 17 2022**
Just delete the

> pubspec.lock

inside your flutter application.

**location of that file: (Flutter project name)/pubspec.lock**

then run

> flutter clean

and then

> flutter pub get

it will just again create that .lock file for and you are good to go.